# What is the adjectival form of "turmoil"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

What is the adjectival form of "turmoil"?

Might it be "turbulent"? I have a feeling that that isn't it, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As simchona said, there is no adjective derived from *turmoil*, nor any adjective with a related etymology. So in the strict sense, there is no adjective form of the word *turmoil*.

For a word with the appropriate meaning, I would suggest *tumultuous*:

> (adj) disruptive, riotous, troubled, tumultuous, turbulent (characterized by unrest or disorder or insubordination) "effects of the struggle will be violent and disruptive"; "riotous times"; "these troubled areas"; "the tumultuous years of his administration"; "a turbulent and unruly childhood"

[Source](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=tumultuous)

Answer (score 3):

Having checked the Oxford English Dictionary for *turmoil*, it turns out that it is derived from the Old French *tremouille* or mill-hopper. However, while there are both noun and verb forms of *turmoil*, there is no adjective which shares that etymology. So, I suggest [*turbid*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/turbid):

> 1. not clear or transparent because of stirred-up sediment or the like; clouded; opaque; obscured: the turbid waters near the waterfall.
> 2. thick or dense, as smoke or clouds.
> 3. confused; muddled; disturbed.

Comment: makes sense now!

Answer (score -1):

**tumultuous** can be considered the adjective form of both turmoil and tumult.

another alternative would be **turbid** which literally means *"in turmoil or confusion"*